# A horror comic about vampire in a spaceship, 80's

Tags: story-identification, comics, space, vampire

Looking for a comic I read likely in the late 80's or early 90's. It was about a vampire in a spaceship. The comic was in Finnish, so original language might be anything. Printed in black and white, if original was in color is unknown. It was not a comic book of its own, but a story in a magazine with several stories of different genres. Back in the days, it was common to print color comics in B&W in Finland to save costs.

The story opens in a full- or half page about the ship's bridge. The captain's a woman, and a man is looking at a hologram play of scantly clad women. There are several hologram entertainment units, one was later showing a gladiator fight. People complained that there aren't any new shows to watch. All the crew are humans, no robots, AIs or aliens are about.

The ship finds a lifepod(?) that contains a woman with a serious 80-styled hairdo. After she's rescued, people start dying and she's being sent to quarantine. As in vampire stories, the bodies are drained of blood. The vampire's bite marks are quite large and on the chests of the victims instead of the traditional neck area. All the attacks happened off-screen, so the only a bit gory images were when bodies were discovered.

In the end the captain is the only one left, and she steers the ship towards nearest star, which makes the vampire frightened. Captain's final line is akin "After all, the ship is made of silver."

Drawing style was realistic if idealised, maybe close to the styles of Enrique Romero (but less bare skin) or Alex Raymond. The story definitely is not Wildcat [holiday special](https://oink.blog/category/wildcat/), even if the [final scene](https://oink996646561.files.wordpress.com/2022/05/whs-complete-p6.jpg) is pretty similar. Also, it is not [thirst](https://www.scaryforkids.com/thirst/), since the vampire is female and doesn't [cosplay](https://i0.wp.com/darkworldsquarterly.gwthomas.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/one-8.jpg?w=379&ssl=1) Dr Strange. I think there was no [horror host](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HorrorHost) in the comic either.